# Best practice for storing auth token client side

Tags: client-side, jwt

I'm building a frontend/backend separated system where the user 2FA auths in and gets a JWT back to the client side.

I'm using angular and for now I just store that token in $window.sessionStorage and include it in the header of every request to identify/authorize/authenticate the user.

Is there a more secure store this token on the client side? Right now on logout I delete the key client side and mark it disabled in the  database, but if the user just leaves the browser there's no guarantee that will happen until the token expires (6 hour expire right now).

Any thoughts on this or other threads that already answered it extremely appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this one from stack overflow can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf

Comment: i belive sessionStorage can get cached to disk (for session restore etc), but the `window.name` "transport" seems to be ram-only...

Comment: Please read up on [security for JWT](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way). It is subject to a number of attacks that need to be mitigated. Also look at the [OWASP Cheat Sheet for Session Management](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Also [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-11)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could implement idle timeout on the server and if you see no activity for certain amount of time (say 10 mins) mark the session expired.

Comment: You MUST use session limits on JWT since it is subject to MitM attacks.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]JWTs are meant to authenticate stateless applications and not for sessions, e.g., you will need to build an invalidation mechanism to invalidate individual tokens, a feature that is be required if you are using a session-based application[1](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/). The best practices for securing a JWT are explained by OWASP [JWT Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/JSON_Web_Token_(JWT)_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java). For the secure storage, you should take into account the following:

- Storing the JWT in the sessionStorage container, not as a cookie.
- When you want to make use of the token, use JS to add it as 'bearer'.
- Fingerprint your token to prevent sidejacking attacks.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a bit more context regarding your links (especially the first one). Link only answers are [not good](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @TomK I already include it in my answer.